# LibreOffice, change all numbered lists to bulleted

Tags: libreoffice-writer

LibreOffice 4.x Writer.

Can I change, some way, all numbered lists

```
1. Text
2. Text...
```

to bulleted ones?

```
* Text
* Text...
```

With keeping of all text. Only numbers -> bullets.